# Apply "for" loop to two tables (Dataframes) to add the values in another column

Tags: r

I have a question about `R` programming. If I have two tables like:

```
Table_1

Name        Flag
AA          0
BB          1
CC          0
DD          1
EE          1
FF          1
GG          0
HH          1
```

and

```
Table_2

Name    Value   Flag
AA      20      0
BB      30      1
BB      50      1
CC      40      0
EE      30      1
EE      80      1
GG      20      0
HH      70      1
DD      50      1
FF      10      1
```

I need the output like `Table_3` which is combination of `Table_1` and `Table_2` such as,
whenever there is `Flag` 1 in `Table_2` (common field in both tables) the `value` should be added to `Table_1`.
The `Name` and `Flag` in both tables `Table_1` and `Table_2` will remain same, for ex. if `AA` has `flag 0` in `Table_1` then it will be the same in `Table_2`.
In result table `Table_3` rows must be same as Table_1 and values must be added to respective `Name` from `Table_2`.

**Question:** How can I do it? Is it possible to apply For loop (tables have large number of rows) or simply manipulation of tables.

```
Table_3

Name        Flag   Value
AA          0       0
BB          1       80
CC          0       0
DD          1       50
EE          1       110
FF          1       10
GG          0       0
HH          1       70
```

Comment: You don't need for loops here. Both can be done vectorized (in one operation). Look at `merge` and the `dplyr` package. Your task can be done with a cobination of `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you actually need `Table_1`? We can generate your expected output with only `Table_2`.

The following does the trick:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "EE", "EE", "GG", 
                              "HH", "DD", "FF"), Value = c(20, 30, 50, 40, 30, 80, 20, 70, 
                                                           50, 10), Flag = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Name", 
                                                                                                                        "Value", "Flag"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                          cols = structure(list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "collector")), `   Value` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), `  Flag` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector"))), .Names = c("Name", "   Value", "  Flag")), 
                                                                                                                          default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "tbl", "data.frame"))
library(dplyr)
df %<>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Value = sum(Value * Flag))
```

Output is:

```
  Name Value Flag
1   AA     0    0
2   BB    80    1
3   CC     0    0
4   DD    50    1
5   EE   110    1
6   FF    10    1
7   GG     0    0
8   HH    70    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Added your data for later use:

```
Table1 <- data.frame(Name = paste(LETTERS[seq(1,8,1)],LETTERS[seq(1,8,1)],sep = ""), 
    Flag = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1))
Table2 <- data.frame(Name = c("AA","BB","BB","CC","EE","EE","GG","HH","DD","FF"), 
                     Value = c(20,30,50,40,30,80,20,70,50,10),
                     Flag = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1))
```

Try using packages, the dplyr package for example is really mighty.
Here are 2 ways to combine your tables: (Table 1 is not really needed for that since Table2 has all the information)

```
library(dplyr)

Table3.1 <- Table2 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value*Flag))

Table3.2 <- Table2 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
summarise(Value = sum(Value[Flag == 1]))
```

Result:

```
  Name  Value
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 AA         0
2 BB        80
3 CC         0
4 DD        50
5 EE       110
6 FF        10
7 GG         0
8 HH        70
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Code works fine, but I need both tables for further use in data processing That's why I need the result like in Table_3 which has similar columns like Table_1 has, or directly sum up values in Table_1.